# Adding Google Analytics event handlers

Tags: gatsby

On a current Gatsbyjs site build I need to record some (click) events in Google Analytics.

I'm at a loss as to where I would add my custom code to listen for the events I want to send off.

What is the common practice for adding the js code to listen across pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best place to do this is to write a plugin with a `gatsby-browser.js` that implements https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry

This will get called as soon as Gatsby starts running in the client and you can then start listening for click events.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyle